# J1 visa and holding equity in a non-US startup

Tags: united-states, non-resident, start-up, visa, equity

I hold equity in a start-up based in Singapore as one of its technical advisers on its board. I am not a co-founder, investor or an employee of the company. I do not receive any salary. I am an Indian citizen.

This fall, I will go to the US on a J-1 visa as a postdoc. Am I allowed to retain the equity and remain an adviser to the non-US startup while on a J-1 visa?

-RD

Answer (score 1):

Your holding equity in a non-US business has nothing to do with your J1 visa status.

If you were receiving *income* from that company, and if you later become a resident in the US, *then* you would be liable for taxes to the IRS.  But since you mentioned there is no money exchange, there shouldn't be any problem.